# I erase the Macintosh HD and now i cannot install macos again

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, disk-format

I decide to buy a macbook, but I have a problem with the mac os. Because the MacBook has an intel processor after the last update the keyboard stops working, lagging, and all of this. I decide to go to disk utilities and erase the Macintosh HD as the manual says and install again the os that had when I bought it. After that, anytime I boot it I get the folder with the question mark. I tried to boot with the combinations command + r and command + options + r. It try to recover from internet but I take the error -1008F. Any ideas ?!?!?! I will be greatfull for any help!!!!

**MacBook Details**
The model is Macbook Pro with the Intel prossecor, model 1989.

**UPDATE**
Finally with the command + option + r combination and internet connection via Ethernet cable it worked and download the os again.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I've linked you to several very good descriptions of the process and possible challenges. If you can edit in some details - like what model Mac and which screen you get stuck at - perhaps we can help more. Recovering from the internet is the way forward for you I believe from your description

Comment: Thank you a lot for your response. The internet recover failed everytime. There any possibility to broke the hard drive and needs to change ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the model year or any other other information that could help identify the model year. Also, do you have any other PCs or Macs. Often, you can use a different machine to create an installation USB flash drive.

Comment: The model is Macbook Pro with the Intel prossecor, model 1989. I make a bootable usb from other mac with the os that came with, I select to boot from the usb and everytime try to make internet recovery and show this error code 1008F

Comment: Yes - it's possible - can you edit some of these details in the body of the question? That might trigger a review to reopen it

Comment: I updated the info, if you need more info let me know. FYI I finally it works the internet recovery as I write above. Thank you !!!